# Using Jquery/Ajax to display a result of codeigniter function in view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm currently working on a project by using codeigniter. Where I have a view page called **dashboard.php**. In dashboard, my task is to display a graph. From **dashbord.php** I'm calling the controller function which is `stat()`. I have created the graph using Morris.js and which is located in **stat.php**.

**controller function stat()**

```
  public function stat()
  {
    $this->load->view('template/admin_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('merchant/stat', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer', $data);
  }
```

**view page stat.php**

```
<script>
$(function() {
     Morris.Area({
        element: 'morris-area-chart-scan-payment',
        data: [
        {
            period: 'Mon',
            spoint: 2666,
            mpayment: null,
        }, 
        {
            period: 'Tue',
            spoint: 2778,
            mpayment: 1350,
        }, 
        {
            period: 'Wed',
            spoint: 4912,
            mpayment: 1969,
        } 
      ], 

      xkey: 'period',
     ykeys: ['spoint', 'mpayment'],
     labels: ['Scan Point', 'Payment'],
     parseTime: false,
     pointSize: 2,
     hideHover: 'auto',
     resize: true
     });
  });
 </script>

 <div id="morris-area-chart-scan-payment"></div>
```

**dashboard.php the view page**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```

I have created a div tag in the view page **dashboard.php**. How can I display the graph in **stat.php** in **dashboard.php** using JQuery/Ajax ?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: graph in stat.php in dashboard.php meanse?

Comment: graph is in a separate view file which is stat.php. What i want is to display the graph in dashboard using Jquery and Ajax.

Comment: i think its not possible(not tested) because chart have many affection related to jquery so thats not good method. you have to call ajax from dashbord.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codeigniter should return the `array` of morris data as `json` on the url which will be requested in the `ajax` below

```
$(function() {
  var morris_area = Morris.Area({
    element: 'morris-area-chart-scan-payment',
    data: [
      {
        period: 'Mon',
        spoint: 2666,
        mpayment: null,
      }, 
      {
        period: 'Tue',
        spoint: 2778,
        mpayment: 1350,
      }, 
      {
        period: 'Wed',
        spoint: 4912,
        mpayment: 1969,
      } 
    ], 
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['spoint', 'mpayment'],
    labels: ['Scan Point', 'Payment'],
    parseTime: false,
    pointSize: 2,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
  });

  $('.some-button').on('click', function loadMorrisData() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://your-test-url.something",
      success: function(data) {
        morris_area.setData(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I have a number of graphs to display in dashboard. So, It would be better that all the graphs are in different files. Is there any way to call those files using Jquery and Ajax?

Comment: I think you should add an `AjaxController` inside your Codeigniter project so you can add different methods (with different routes) for different charts

Answer (score 0):

where is your callback URL ?

you must set a callback url where you want to sent the data and receive the value .